# I keep on getting error when trying to get role object by rolename [discord.js]

Tags: node.js, discord.js

**CODE**

```
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === args[1]);                
const member = message.mentions.members.first(); 
member.roles.remove(role).catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Here args[1] is the name of the role.
This code was working before but now it shows this error.

**ERROR:**

```
   TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not an Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.
        at GuildMemberRoleManager.remove
 [Symbol(code)]: 'INVALID_TYPE'
```

EDIT: **role** is **UNDEFINED**

Comment: When this happens, is `role` actually a role object, or is it null/undefined?

Comment: the role here is undefined

Comment: the roles.cache is only populated after you do a roles.fetch(). For example, to fetch all the roles of a guild then search through them you would do message.guild.roles.fetch().get(role => role.name === args[1]); Then on all future uses of the roles list you can use message.guild.roles.cache.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `.remove(roleOrRoles, [reason)]` method of `GuildMemberRoleManager` you need to ensure that you either pass an array of roles, collection of snowflakes or a snowflake as stated in the error that you have. Therefore the correct solution would be:

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === args[1]);                
const member = message.mentions.members.first(); 
member.roles.remove(role.id).catch((e) => console.log(e));
```